# removing filtered cells from tables with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below and what I'm trying to accomplish is:

Remove all the filtered results and create a new table without the filtered results. The problem with this code is that every time when including a new sheet I have to add this line of code for it. Is there any way to workaround this? I've tried using For Each...Next statement but didn't have any success with it.

Edit: the Sheet1, Sheet2 etc. are created earlier in the macro only for this purpose.

```
Sub macro
  
  Worksheets("cat").ListObjects(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste
    Worksheets("cat").Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "cat"
    
    
    Worksheets("dog").ListObjects(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste
    Worksheets("dog").Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Name = "dog"
    
    Worksheets("meow").ListObjects(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Paste
    Worksheets("meow").Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Name = "meow"
    
    
    Worksheets("bark").ListObjects(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Paste
    Worksheets("bark").Delete
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Name = "bark"

End Sub
```

Comment: To iterate between all sheets and do what code does for each sheet is not so complicated, but will you all the time have the sheets 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.? Shouldn't it be better to insert a new sheet each time the code processes a sheet?

Comment: You may want to consider adding a new column called "status" and update it to "inactive" for the displayed rows and then just add filtering logic to this new column as needed,  eg status="" to remove them from view. The benefit of this approach is you can easily report out stats on "inactive" rows - you can't report on data you have deleted ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub macroIterateSh()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, shNew As Worksheet, shName As String
   For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then 'for the case of some other sheets not containing a list object...
            Set shNew = Worksheets.Add(Before:=sh)
            sh.ListObjects(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            shNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            shNew.Paste
            shName = sh.Name: sh.Delete
            shNew.Name = shName
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```